# Use re module in python re.compile('*ab')

Tags: python

I have

> os.listdir('/home/dir/')

with file and file.ab

How can I use regex to list only file.ab on that directory.

When i was use regex with

> re.compile('*ab')

it return

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Use `glob.glob('*.ab')`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Comment: Why not use endswith?

Comment: Error is that in regular expression '*' is used for repeating the previous character, '.' represents any character. Here there is nothing before '*' so nothing to repeat. Use '.*' instead in such scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need regex :

```
[i for i in os.listdir('/home/dir/') if i.endswith(".ab")]
```

Answer (score 4):

Better use `glob`:

```
import glob
print glob.glob('/home/dir/*.ab')
```

Comment: it will have absolute path, and i can't use it as name.